# angularjs ng-repeat on different arrays depending on condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have two arrays. If `ctrl.type == 'group'` I want to do an `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="category in ctrl.categories">
  ...
  <div ng-repeat="item in category.group_items">...</div>
</div>
```

else, it should be

```
<div ng-repeat="category in ctrl.categories">
  ...
  <div ng-repeat="item in category.data.other_items">...</div>
</div>
```

what's the best way to write this? I don't want to rewrite the `...` as it's the same code.

Comment: Initialize a variable `theItems` with one or the other in your controller, and iterate through `theItems`.

Comment: @JBNizet I edited question to show it is in another ng-repeat, is it still best to do as you wrote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function that returns the array in your controller.

```
ctrl.getArray = () => {
  if(ctrl.type === 'something') {
    return ctrl.data.group_items;
  }

  return ctrl.data.other_items;
}
```

And in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.getArray()">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done using ng-switch. Below is my controller code where i have defined two arrays and also defined type on which your data will be shown.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.type = 'something';
    $scope.categories=[{ID:'1',Name:'Test 1'},{ID:'2',Name:'Test 2'},{ID:'3',Name:'Test 3'}];

     $scope.group_items=[{ID:'1',Name:'Group 1'},{ID:'2',Name:'Group 2'},{ID:'3',Name:'Group 3'}];

});
```

Below is the html bindings.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">    
    <div ng-switch="type">
        <div ng-switch-when="group">
           <div ng-repeat="item in categories">
              <p>{{item.Name}}</p>
           </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="something">
           <div ng-repeat="item in group_items">
              <p>{{item.Name}}</p>
           </div>
        </div>        
    </div>    
</div>
```